# Getting all Regex matches to appear in Listbox, VB.NET

Tags: regex, vb.net, listbox, listboxitems

I have a string, example below, where I am trying to use VB.NET to grab all the HotelNames in the string.

Here is my code:

```
    Dim thepage As String = postreqreader.ReadToEnd

    Dim r As New Regex("""HotelName"":"".*""")
    Dim matches As MatchCollection = r.Matches(thepage)
    For Each hotelname As Match In matches
        ListBox1.Items.Add(hotelname.Value.Split("""").GetValue(3))
    Next
```

However this only adds the first HotelName to my ListBox. Any ideas how I can get each HotelName match into my listbox? Thanks for your time!

*shortened String:*

> "HotelName":"Homewood Suites by Hilton Dallas-Arlington","HotelNameShort":"Homewood Suites by Hilton...","HotelNameShortAvailabilityRecommendations":"Homewood Suites by H...","HotelName":"Knights Inn Arlington","HotelNameShort":"Knights Inn Arlington","HotelNameShortAvailabilityRecommendations":"Knights Inn Arlingto...","HotelName":"Howard Johnson Express Inn - Arlington Ballpark / Six Flags","HotelNameShort":"Howard Johnson Express In...","HotelNameShortAvailabilityRecommendations":"Howard Johnson Expre...","HotelName":"Super 8 Arlington/SW","HotelNameShort":"Super 8 Arlington/SW","HotelNameShortAvailabilityRecommendations":"Super 8 Arlington/SW...",

Comment: Thank you very much that worked! Any elaboration would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.*` is greedy. That means it consumes as much as possible, so your first match will take in the **entire** string up until the very last `"`. Then you split that one single match (which actually contains all hotel names) at `"` and take out the third element. (Check out `hotelname.Value.Split("""").Count`, it will be huge)

The trick is to either make the repetition non-greedy, or even better, disallow the repetition to consume `"`:

```
"""HotelName"":""([^""]*)""
```

Now between `"` and `"` we are only repeating non-quote characters, so we can never go past the first closing quote. This alone should solve your problem, but I also added those parentheses. They will not match any actual parentheses, but instead create a capturing group, which makes retrieval of the hotel name even easier:

```
For Each hotelname As Match In matches
    ListBox1.Items.Add(hotelname.Groups[1])
```

For every set of parentheses, the stuff that is matched inside them will be put into one element of `match.Groups`, counting opening parentheses from left to right. The regex matching already does all that you need to get the individual values, so why perform a second splitting step.